# Gwt set label text as lesser than(<) sign using UiBinder

Tags: html, gwt, uibinder

I have the following code for a widget in UiBinder

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
<b:Label>&lt;</b:Label>
<b:TextBox ui:field="lowerLimit" addStyleNames="lowerLimitTextBox"></b:TextBox>
<b:Button icon="COPY" addStyleNames="copyAll copyAllLower">Copy To All</b:Button>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

On the page it turns up as `&lt;` instead of < 
How can I specify the label text to show up as < from within UiBinder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried like this ?

```
<g:Label  text="&lt;"></g:Label>
```

Make sure your `doctype` should like `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<g:HTML HTML="&lt;"></g:HTML>
```

Instead of Label.
Because Label shows only **plain** Text not **Html** text.

Comment: Actually I'm using gwt-bootstrap and I get styles with the labels. I would prefer doing this within the label only. If there is no possibility then I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Escape it. `<b:Label> \< </b:Label>`